# MapServer with Oracle 12

Tags: mapserver, oracle-spatial

I'm running MapServer on Windows (with the msplugin_oracle.dll plugin) to create some WMS layers from SDO geometry stored in Oracle 11 database. I take the binaries from this very nice [site](http://www.gisinternals.com/). The problem I have is that the client who runs the database is planning to swap to using Oracle 12.

Can this cause any problems?

Or will it run smoothly?

Does anyone have any experience with getting SDO geometry out of Oracle 12 using MapServer?

Couldn't find much info online.

Comment: the only difference (especially if he is going to use a pdb) is that the connection string differs, apart from that there shouldn't be any problem (some applications do have a problem mainly cause you define the connection string through a UI and it cannot end up as it should)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should not cause any problem. The windows server where you run Mapserver runs the Oracle client library. I assume that it comes from Oracle 11.2. Oracle client libraries and servers are compatible across versions, both upwards and downwards - except for very old versions. In other words you don't need to upgrade the Oracle client on your Mapserver server.

As for database connection strings, they remain the same. Except if your customer decides to use Oracle 12c's multi-tenant facility. If so, then you need to make sure that your database connection string points to the the correct PDB, i.e. uses the proper service name (not SID).

And for SDO_GEOMETRY types, they are compatible from one version to the next. As a matter of fact their definition and content has not changed since the first version they appeared in (that was 8i - ages ago).